# fetch record from multi tables with FK constrains

Tags: mysql

i am trying to fetch data from multiple tables (3 levels). the scanario is that customer send request to the agent and agent handle it. for customer i have table customer

```
    -----------------------------------------
    customerid | customername | fk_personid
       1       |     abc      |     1
       2       |     xyz      |     4
    ------------------------------------------
```

customer send request to the agent who would handle it

```
   ----------------------------------------
    agnetid    | agentname    | fk_personid
       6       |     asd      |     1
       7       |     fgh      |     4
    ---------------------------------------
```

both above tables are connected through their parent table person

```
   ------------------------------------------
    personid   | personname   |  personemail 
       1       |     abc      |    as@m.com
       2       |     xyz      |    vb@df.com
    -----------------------------------------
```

now there is another table name Request like in which both forign keys are composite PK for request table

```
    ------------------------------------------
    FK_custmid |   FK_agentid |  requestype 
       1       |       1      |    type one
       2       |       2      |    type two
    -----------------------------------------
```

now the final thing is there are six different types of requests that are connected to request table(parent) throug FK. below is the one table for single type rest all are like the same.
in the below table the above composite PK are FK's

```
   -----------------------------------------------------------
    req_id  |  req_FK_custmid | req_FK_agentid |  requestype 
       1    |        1        |       1        |   type one
       2    |        2        |       2        |   type two
    ----------------------------------------------------------
```

ahhhhhhh now keeping all these tables in mind i have to show details about a request generated customer i.e i need

```
  -------------------------------------------------
   req_id | requestype |  customer_id | agent_id 
     1    |   type one |      1       |    1
  -------------------------------------------------
```

i hope you guys cod get my point and could help me in finding solution for it. i also tried it my self like

```
  SELECT * FROM Agent,Request,Person,customer where Request.customer_idcutomer = customer.idcustomer and Request.Agent_idAgent = Agent.idAgent and Person.idPerson = customer.Person_idPerson and Person.idPerson = Agent.Person_idPerson
```

another approach this is incomplete as because i didnt know how to complete it further. 1 in the end part of query is hard coded which shuld be be but i dont know how get is dynamicall

```
  SELECT request.SPOC_id, request.order_created, request.order_updated
  FROM request
  WHERE Agent_idAgent = ( 
  SELECT agent.idAgent
  FROM agent
  WHERE agent.idAgent =1 ) 
  LIMIT 0 , 30
```

there are so many other approches i tried but every one didn't give me what i want i am basiclly stuck on a point to get the order/request type the customer has placed.

NOTE: there are some fields that you will see in query but i didnt mention in my tables above just to save time and all the data i put is dummy and may not synchronized to each other.

Note: if you suggest me to change the tables and theirs connections structure let me know and guid me if am doing wrong in it.

Comment: From where _"order_id"_ and _"order_type"_ came?

Comment: these wod be alias for requestid and request type

Comment: now i edit my question

Comment: @kwk.stack could you post a sample of the what the result would like after the query runs?

Comment: i posted it above the the last most table is the result

Comment: Sorry @kwk.stack but I am not able to understand what result you actually want in the end. Can you elaborate a bit further(What is the actual problem)?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an inner query, use joins.

Based on your hard coded query, the answer seems to be

```
SELECT request.SPOC_id, request.order_created, request.order_updated
FROM request inner join agents 
ON agents.idAgent = request.FK_agentid
WHERE Agent_idAgent = 1
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

In order to make this query more general, you need to replace the hard coded '1' with a parameter (your syntax may vary)

```
SELECT request.SPOC_id, request.order_created, request.order_updated
FROM request inner join agents 
ON agents.idAgent = request.FK_agentid
WHERE Agent_idAgent = :p1
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

How do you use the parameter? The query presumably is being called from some programming language. In Delphi, I would write the following

```
with MyQuery do
 begin
  parambyname ('p1').asinteger:= 7;
  open;
  ...
  close
 end;
```

This would retrieve all the requests for agent 7. As your table design does not allow an agent to have a name (the name is to be found in the Person table), it's more difficult to show how to retrieve all the requests for the agent whose name is kwk.stack.

```
SELECT request.SPOC_id, request.order_created, request.order_updated
FROM request inner join agents 
ON agents.idAgent = request.agent_agentid
inner join person on person.idperson = agents.person_idperson
WHERE person.name = 'kwk.stack'
```

The above is based on the question as it was first asked. Edits to the question may mean that the above no longer answers the question being asked.

I strongly suggest that you change the names of your tables - these are normally plural, eg People, Agents, Requests, etc - and the field names within the tables - replace 'agent_agentid' with 'agent'; 'person_idperson' with 'person', etc.

Comment: thanx for reply but this is the issue i am facing that i dont have any idea what to put next in the place of hardcoded 1 to get desired result

Comment: THATS lil better solution but i need to ask how to acces the name of request type e.g movies, mobiles or any thing customer request from an agent should also display in resulted table

Comment: @kwk.stack: Ask a new question, giving the complete table structure. Basically, you have to join at least one other table to your query. The 'Requests' table contains a foreign key to the 'RequestTypes' table, so you would link to this table and add to the select query a field like RequestTypes.Name.